# binary in_array search

Tags: php, arrays

I use a lot of `in_array` functions and it seems to bog down my loading times. I found the following code in the [`in_array` php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php). The writer states "this function is five times faster than in_array(). It uses a binary search and should be able to be used as a direct replacement."

```
function fast_in_array($elem, $array) 
{
   $top = sizeof($array) -1;
   $bot = 0;
   while($top >= $bot) 
   {
      $p = floor(($top + $bot) / 2);
      if ($array[$p] < $elem) $bot = $p + 1;
      elseif ($array[$p] > $elem) $top = $p - 1;
      else return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

However the function works, but only half of the time, sometimes it doesnt output everything it should be outputting for example if I have an array with apples, oranges, and lemons, and do an match for apples and oranges it will only print oranges or something weird. Could someone please explain to me what exactly this script does, and why it doesn't work as a substitute for `in_array`.

Comment: One reason it doesn't work is because PHP comparisons are broken for heterogeneous datatypes. What data are you storing in the array exactly?

Comment: "this function is five times faster" --- it's lie

Comment: Well for example, when i tested this code I was matching allowed or 'editable' row columns with queried columns. bit difficult to explain. but needless to say its not sorted.

Comment: it would be even faster if you flip the array and use array_key_exists instead (`array_fill_keys($yourarray,1)`). keep in mind that this will only work if the elements are unique though. edit: values have to be scalar too.

Comment: @Mark: unique and scalar

Comment: @Alex: what are they then? you could always use a custom hash-set implementation, but.. I don't know if it would yield any benefit.

Comment: If you're having performance problems it's probably because you're using the wrong datatype to model your data.

Comment: i think im just going to store the in_array values since they only get generate once a new cms page with new fields is created. but tbh loading times arnt as high as i let on - i think most of it is from jquery related bs

Comment: @Alex: I'm wearing of caching results. They have a tendency of getting out of sync. How many elements are in your array? If there's like 100 or less, it probably doesn't even matter if you're doing a linear search.

Comment: its probably about 10-50 depending. its just that syncing wont be a problem because its sort of a one time deal, but everytime  the form gets generated the same inputs are created from the allowable inputs. so its kindof redundant to do it everytime

Comment: I feel the urge to add that this should not be 5 times faster. in_array is of linear complexity, the presented function of logarithmic complexity, the bigger the array, the bigger the time difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It performs a binary search, which assumes the array is in sorted total order. If the array is not sorted, it will fail.

Comment: so basically since the data comes in unsorted, and since that would require more processing, this will not be in any shape or form 'faster'

Comment: @Alex: that depends. sorting takes O(n log n) time, then a binary search takes O(log n) time. vs regular in_array which takes O(n) time...so..yeah, you're right. unless you're performing multiple searches and only one sort, plain old in_array is better than sort+binary search.

Comment: Also, if the array has heterogeneous data, it can't be sorted reliably in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

This function does binary search. It only works if the array is sorted.

P.S. The claim that it works "five times faster" is pretty funny.

Comment: yea i thought so too, but i decided to give it a whirl